# Python: How to make sparql queries to extract data from Dbpedia?

Tags: python, sparql

I want to extract data of Swiss cities from `Dbpedia` using `sparql` in python.

```
import rdflib
sparql = SPARQLWrapper("http://dbpedia.org/sparql")
sparql.setQuery("""
    PREFIX dbpedia-owl:  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
    PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource>
    PREFIX dbpprop: <http://dbpedia.org/property>
    SELECT DISTINCT ?citylabel ?countrylabel ?pop ?country
    WHERE{ 
       ?city rdf:type dbpedia-owl:City.
       ?city rdfs:label ?citylabel.
       ?city dbpedia-owl:populationTotal ?pop.
       ?city dbpedia-owl:country ?country.
       ?country rdfs:label ?countrylabel.
       FILTER (  ?country = dbpedia:Switzerland)
    }
""")
sparql.setReturnFormat(JSON)
results = sparql.query().convert()
```

But it `results` contains no values. Why?

Comment: your query is wrong. Test it here: https://dbpedia.org/sparql

Comment: yes, I missed a point. I did correct it.

Comment: the prefix `dbpedia` is wrong. It's missing the ending slash

Comment: just for the future: the same holds for `dbpprop` although not used in this query